# Contruction of vectors

Tags: geometry, vectors

Draw the vectors $\vec{a}$ and $\vec{b}$ with $|\vec{a}|=a=2\ cm$ and $|\vec{b}|=b=3\ cm$, these have angle $40^{\circ}$ between them.

Contruct the vectors:

(a) $\vec{c}=2\vec{a}-\vec{b}$

(b) $\vec{d}=\vec{a}+2\vec{b}$

(c) $\vec{e}$ such that $5\vec{a}-2\vec{e}=\vec{b}$

I have done the following for (a) and (b):

[image]

As for (c) do we solve for $\vec{e}$ first and then do the graphs?

Comment: yes you could solve for $e$ and then draw. For (b), you may want to draw a vector parallel to $\vec a$ of the same magnitude at the end of $\vec {2b}$.

Comment: I did that in that on the paper, above I have only the result. I have also an other similar post : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4039713/drawing-vectors-in-3dimension could you take a look? @MathLover

Comment: I have also an other question... The length od vector $\vec{c}$ is not equal to $2a-b=4-3=1$, is it? @MathLover

Comment: No it is not, they are forming a triangle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can proceed geometrically like you did in (a) and (b). The vector going from  the tip of $\mathbf b$ to the tip of $5\mathbf a$ is $-\mathbf b + 5\mathbf a = 2 \mathbf e$, and now you can scale this down by $1/2$.

Comment: I got it! Thanks!! I have also an other similar post : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4039713/drawing-vectors-in-3dimension could you take a look?

Comment: I have also an other question... The length od vector $\vec{c}$ is not equal to $2a-b=4-3=1$, is it?

Comment: @MaryStar No the distance must be found using trigonometry. You know an angle and two side lengths, so law of cosines will help.

Comment: Ok! Thank you!! :-)