# Drawing vectors in 3dimension

Tags: geometry, vectors

The vectors $\vec{a}, \vec{b}, \vec{c}$ are as follows:

[image]

with $a=2\ cm, \ b=2.5\ cm, \ c=3\ cm$.

Construct the vector

(a) $\vec{u}=2\vec{a}+\vec{b}-3\vec{c}$

(b) $\vec{v}$ such that $3\vec{a}-2\vec{b}+3\vec{c}+\vec{v}=\vec{0}$

(c) $\vec{w}$ such that $\vec{a}+3\vec{b}-4\vec{c}+2\vec{w}=\vec{0}$

For (a) I have done the following:

[image]

Is that correct?

For (b) and (c) we have to solve as for the unknown vector first, right?

Comment: What is the connection with the title ?

Comment: $\vec u$ should be in the opposite direction.

Comment: Why? Isn't the subtraction from the endpoint of the  first vector $(2\vec{a}+\vec{b})$ to the endpoint of the second vector $(3\vec{c})$ ? @MathLover

Comment: That is $3 \vec c - (2 \vec a + \vec b)$. You need the opposite sign.

Comment: Ahh ok! I see!! And at (b) and (c) we solve first for the unknown vectors and then we followthe same procedure as in (a), right? @MathLover

Comment: Yes that is correct.

Comment: Great!! Thank you very much!! :-) @MathLover

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a) is not correct; look carefully as to in which direction c is going, and mind that it says *minus 3* so *-3c*, so the added -3c vector should be in the opposite direction of the original c.

Comment: Thank you!! :-)